# How send params from tag helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I want pass params from view to controller, but dont know how make it with `asp.net tag-helpers`. What i make wrong? Params not received on controller.

```
<form asp-controller="Role" asp-action="Create" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Name" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Name" class="form-control" />

        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How pass data from `inputbox` to `controller`?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string rolename)
        {
            try
            {
                this.context.Roles.Add(new IdentityRole()
                {
                    Name = rolename
                });
                this.context.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Comment: Please post your model class

Comment: model is standard.   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {...}

Answer (score 2):

In your action method change `rolename` to `name`. The default model binder doesn't know where to initialize this `rolename` from. Additionally you can inspect what is posted on the server via fiddler.